# How to cite a DynaMed publication correctly using the "vancouver" bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I am trying to the cite the following thing correctly. I have these instructions.

> How to cite:  National Library of Medicine, or "Vancouver style" (International Committee of Medical Journal Editors):
>
> DynaMed Plus [Internet].
> Ipswich (MA): EBSCO Information Services. 1995--. Record No. 909124,
> Electrocardiogram (ECG); [updated 2016 Apr 20, cited place cited date
> here]; [about 30 screens]. Available from
> http://www.dynamed.com/login.aspx?direct=true&site=DynaMed&id=909124.
> Registration and login required.

.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\cite{dynmedECG}
\bibliographystyle{vancouver}   % Mico; https://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/administration-and-support-services/library/public/LaTeX-example-Vancouver-branded-jan-2016.pdf  
\bibliography{thesis}
\end{document}
```

My wrong proposal in file.bib

```
@article{dynmedECG,
   author = "DynaMed Plus [Internet]", 
   journal = "Ipswich (MA): EBSCO Information Services", 
   year  = "1995 - ", 
   title = "Record No. 909124, Electrocardiogram (ECG)", 
   note = "[updated 2016 Apr 20, cited place Riga cited date Nov 20 2016]; [about 30 screens]. Available from http://www.dynamed.com/login.aspx?direct=true&site=DynaMed&id=909124. Registration and login required."
}
```

Output after many iterations

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `dynmedECG' on page 10 undefined on input line
 589.
```

### Testing to apply Mico's proposal.

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23508124/) are my complete packages which may cause the complication.
[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23508342/) my .bib file.

Fig. 1 Output in my current setting

[image]

Output: question marks in the body when citing to the source

Output

```
! Misplaced alignment tab character &. l.14 ...://www.dynamed.com/login.aspx?direct=true& site=DynaMed&id=909124. ? ! Misplaced alignment tab character &. l.14 ...d.com/login.aspx?direct=true&site=DynaMed& id=909124.
```

My proposal for the solution in .bib. with `{\&}` but I still cannot get it work; I also tried with `\&`

```
% Mico
@misc{dynmedECG,
   author = "{DynaMed Plus [Internet]. Ipswich (MA): EBSCO Information Services}", 
   year  = "1995--", 
   note = "{Record No. 909124, Electrocardiogram (ECG)}", 
   howpublished = "{[updated 2016 Apr 20, cited place: Riga; cited date: Nov 20 2016]; [about 30 screens]. 
        Available from \url{http://www.dynamed.com/login.aspx?direct=true{\&}site=DynaMed{\&}id=909124}. 
        Registration and login required.}"
}
```

TeXLive: 2016
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: Since the instruction is to use "Vancouver" style, why are you using the `unsrtnat` bibliography style instead of the `vancouver` bibliography style? Also, why are you using the `@article` entry type for a piece which clearly wasn't published in an academic journal?

Comment: @Mico Thank you! I thought `unsrtnat` is Vancouver. I changed the body. Still, I get no entry with the bib entry.

Comment: The `vancouver` style places the `year` field soon after the `author` field (and, if present, the `title` field). That's what appears to be required here. In contrast, the `unsrtnat` style places the `year` field pretty much at the very end of the formatted entry.

Comment: Judging by the screenshot you posted, you may not have loaded the `natbib` package with the option `numbers`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Use the `vancouver` bibliography style. Unlike the `unsrtnat` bibliography style, `vancouver` inserts the year field immediately after the `author` and `title` fields.
- Since the entry contains a URL string, be sure to load the `url` package and to encase the entire URL string in a `\url` directive.
- Use the `@misc` entry type for this entry, as it's not a piece that was published in an (academic) journal.
- Be sure to encase the entire `author` field in an extra pair of curly braces, to inform BibTeX that this is a single, "corporate" author.
- The ordering of the fields recommended by Dynamed -- author, address and publisher, year, and only then title, followed by the URL and some final, ancillary information -- is rather uncommon, and it can't be handled by the `vancouver` style if you were to use the usual field names `title` and `howpublished` unless you were to hack the style file, which I don't recommend you do. To handle this rather uncommon ordering of the fields, I suggest that you

  - place the address and publisher information at the end of the `author` field;
  - place the contents of the `title` field into the `note` field, and thus not have a `title` field at all -- this is actually permissible with the `@misc` entry type; and thus
  - use both `note` and `howpublished` and fields.

Observe that you should (actually, must!) encase the URL string in a `\url` directive.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{thesis.bib}
@misc{dynmedECG,
   %% Some unusual aspects of this entry:
   %% - 'author' field also contains address and publisher information
   %% - 'note' field contains what appears to be the title of the publication
   %% - 'howpublished' field contains all remaining information
   author = "{DynaMed Plus [Internet]. Ipswich (MA): EBSCO Information Services}", 
   year  = "1995--", 
   note = "{Record No. 909124, Electrocardiogram (ECG)}", 
   howpublished = "[updated 2016 Apr 20, cited place: Riga; cited
        date: Nov 20 2016]; [about 30 screens]. Available from
        \url{http://www.dynamed.com/login.aspx?direct=true&site=DynaMed&id=909124}. 
        Registration and login required."
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}     % create numeric-style citatin call-outs
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url} % allow line breaks at hyphens and spaces

\begin{document}
\cite{dynmedECG}
\bibliographystyle{vancouver}  
\bibliography{thesis}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I am loading `url`, see here complete http://paste.ubuntu.com/23508124/ I enclose URL string with `\url{...}`. I just copy-pasted your proposal to by .bib file.

Comment: Fixed but does not help. The condition persists. Is there anything critical mistakes in my .bib file which may cause the conflict http://paste.ubuntu.com/23508342/ ? The new entry is at the end. Please, see the body for my output.

Comment: @Masi - Clearly, as the screenshot above shows, my answer works properly. If your software doesn't allow you to copy and paste my code correctly, then it's a matter of your software, which *you* need to fix. I don't think there's anything more for me to do here. Period.

Comment: It is not editor problem. I reproduced it now in Vim and Emacs. The problem is caused by the symbols `&` in `howpublished`? How can you overcome it?